# Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments

Tags: r

Developing regression model using *neuralnet package*,I have checked that there is no `NA` or `NAN` values and also there are only predictors in the test data set.

```
n <- names(y[673:29952,])
f <- as.formula(paste("y[673:29952,]$x1 ~ ", paste(n[!n %in% "y[673:29952,]$x1"], collapse = " + ")))

  nn1 <- neuralnet(f,data=y[673:29952,],hidden=5,linear.output=T)

   pr.nn <- compute(nn1,y[29953:30432,2:8])
```

kindly help me to resolve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question does not contain a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162). It is therefore hard to understand your problem and give you an appropriate answer. Please make your data available (e.g. by using `dput()`) or use one of the example data sets in R. Also, add the minimal code required to reproduce your problem to your post.

Comment: Here is a reproducible example. `library(neuralnet); neuralnet(Species~Sepal.Length,iris,hidden=2)`